# Disable/enable commandButton depending on required fields of current form?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

What is the best approach to disable a `commandButton` if the fields with `required=true` are not filled with values?

The button should be disabled on first page load, and only be enabled in case all required fields are fields with values.

By best approach i mean no javascript and minimum-code :-)

In addition it would be excellent if the `commandButton` is only enabled when all `validators` evaluate to true.

Using PF 3.2

**EDIT**

- by best approach i also mean, it should only be evaluate on client-side

Comment: Client side without JavaScript ???

Comment: With javascript, this will be easy to maintain and light for your client (internet browser like iexplore, firefox, chrome, etc) and server (web application server). With lots of ajax calls per every "onchange" on your input components, it will become very heavy. If you don't want to use JavaScript because you don't know, learn some, if you don't want for a non functional requirement restriction, explain to the person in charge why ajax implementation would be a very bad approach and JavaScript will be your friend.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible for two reasons.

1. For client side validation, you would definitely require javascript.
2. The `required` attribute of components is stored server side ONLY, the client has no idea of which fields are required by default.

Without using `required`, you could achieve this in client-side as following. `validateContent` should contain the logic to disable the `commandButton`.

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.text}" >
    <pe:javascript event="keyup" execute="validateContent();"/>
</h:inputText>
```

If going to server is okay, then you could do this:

```
<h:inputText id="test1" value="#{bean.text}" required="true" immediate="true">
    <f:ajax listener="#{bean.makeDisable()}" render="test2" />
</h:inputText>
</h:commandButton id="test2" value="commandButton1" disabled="#{bean.disable}" />
```

And in the bean:

```
  private String text;
  private boolean disable;

  // setter & getter of text

  public boolean isDisable()
  {
    return disable;
  }

  public void makeDisable(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
  {
    if(text == null || text.equals(""))
      this.disable=true;
    else
      this.disable=false;
  }
```

This basically will load the `commandButton` disabled on initial load and it will only be enabled on entering any value in text field.

Comment: Because there are other required fields on the form, your ajax functionality will not actually call its server side event because validation will have failed.

Comment: Oh yes, the fields also need to be `immediate`.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but I would hardly call it the "best way".

You would need to supply an `ajax` tag for change events on each field.  Each field would have to be `immediate` to skip initial validation and `process` will need to be set to `@this`.

In an event listener you can check if values exist for each of the required fields and if so then set a boolean field that determines if the commandButton is disabled or not.

These `ajax` tags will need to `render` `@this` as well as the `commandButton`.

But even then there is a LOT of Javascript actually going on, just none that you would have to write directly.